# How to log subprocess data to tg bot

Tags: python, subprocess, python-asyncio, popen

I run the jar like this:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.call([java8_path, '-jar', core_path])
```

and everything works and the logs of the jar file are output to the console, but I cannot specify one thing

I need the logs from the jar file not to be output directly to the console, but to be sent to me by the tg bot

```py
from aiogram import types

async def send_logs(jar_log_text: str):
    await bot.send_message(0000000, jar_log_text)
```

but I don't know threads and subprocesses and don't understand how to do it.

Comment: Have you tried `.call(..., cwd=core_path_parent)`? [`call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) has pretty much the same arguments as [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

Comment: @ivvija Oh thanks, I solved the first problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `subprocess.call()` use `subprocess.Popen` with `PIPE`. This snippet runs your jar file and sends it's output as string to your `send_log` function continuously.

*(Until your process is alive, the value of `p.poll()` is `None` so the while loop stops whenever the process ends.)*
Since there is no `poll` method in `asyncio`, I use this method (`is_running`)

```py
import contextlib
import asyncio

async def is_running(proc):
    with contextlib.suppress(asyncio.TimeoutError):
        await asyncio.wait_for(proc.wait(), 1e-6)
    return proc.returncode is None

async def main():
    global proc
    server_path = '../servers_community/cree'
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*[JAVA8_PATH, '-jar', 'spigot-1.12.2.jar'], stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, cwd=server_path)
    while await is_running(proc):
        text = (await proc.stdout.readline()).decode("cp866")
        if text:
            await bot.send_message(0000000, text)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: did you mean `readline`?

Comment: everything works, but how to do it with asyncio library?

Comment: I think it should work now.

Comment: how to do it with asyncio library?

Comment: I've edited my answer. it has asyncio library inside it.

Comment: help pls, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76229621/

Comment: @CreeperHack Nice edit. I'm happy that you found the problem. I wanted to test your code with telegram to see the error but I had trouble with connecting to VPN since telegram is banned in my region.