# aiogram handlers stop working after subprocess logging

Tags: python, subprocess, telegram, aiogram

i don't understand but if i run the jar file and it prints the initial logs, all the handlers stop working

handlers are still working until all the initial logs come to me in tg

```
async def main():
    server_path = '../servers_community/cree'
    with subprocess.Popen([JAVA8_PATH, '-jar', 'spigot-1.12.2.jar'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=server_path) as p:
        while p.poll() is None:
            text = p.stdout.readline().decode("cp866")
            if text:
                await bot.send_message(00000000, text)

@dp.message_handler()
async def input_cmd(msg):
    print(msg.text)

asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(main())
executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```